# Regular Expression to change a string but not string+string2

Tags: regex, python-3.x, notepad++

I have a large file with several lines containing localhost and localhost:portnumber(port number is not constant.it can be 4070,8080,9090) in them.I want to change all the localhost or localhost:portnumber to localhost:4080.But i don't want to change the localhost:4080.Simple search and replace (localhost to localhost:4080)will change localhost:portnumber to localhost:4080:portnumber.Any way to do this with regex.Preferbly in notepad++

example input:

```
https://localhost/subservice1 
https://localhost:4080/subservice1 
https://localhost:1090/subservice1 
https://localhost/subservice2
```

output should be

```
https://localhost:4080/subservice1 
https://localhost:4080/subservice1 
https://localhost:4080/subservice1 
https://localhost:4080/subservice2
```

Comment: Search for `localhost(?::4080)?`and replace it with `localhost:4080`

Comment: Just replace `localhost/` with `localhost:4080/`

Comment: Thanks for all answers.All answers are correct.I changed the question a bit.I want to change all port in my config file.I forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This should work**

**REGEXP: For Python and Notepad++**

```
(?:.*)(?:\blocalhost\/|localhost:4080\/)(.*)
```

**REPLACE:**

```
https://localhost:4080/$1
```

**PYTHON CODE:**

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"(?:.*)(?:\blocalhost\/|localhost:4080\/)(.*)"

test_str = ("https://localhost/subservice1 \n"
    "https://localhost:4080/subservice1 \n"
    "https://localhost/subservice1 \n"
    "https://localhost/subservice2")

subst = "https://localhost:4080/$1"

# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

**REGEXP:**

**INPUT:**

```
https://localhost/subservice1 
https://localhost:4080/subservice1 
https://localhost/subservice1 
https://localhost/subservice2
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
https://localhost:4080/subservice1 
https://localhost:4080/subservice1 
https://localhost:4080/subservice1 
https://localhost:4080/subservice2
```

**See:** https://regex101.com/r/kbPHd6/1

**Try Python Code:** http://ideone.com/yNoYzv

*If i help u, mark me as correct answer and vote up.*

**Explanation:**

```
(?: Non-capturing group. Groups multiple tokens together without creating a capture group.
. Dot. Matches any character except line breaks.
* Star. Match 0 or more of the preceding token.
)
(?: Non-capturing group. Groups multiple tokens together without creating a capture group.
\b Word boundary. Matches a word boundary position such as whitespace, punctuation, or the start/end of the string.
l Character. Matches a "l" character (char code 108).
o Character. Matches a "o" character (char code 111).
c Character. Matches a "c" character (char code 99).
a Character. Matches a "a" character (char code 97).
l Character. Matches a "l" character (char code 108).
h Character. Matches a "h" character (char code 104).
o Character. Matches a "o" character (char code 111).
s Character. Matches a "s" character (char code 115).
t Character. Matches a "t" character (char code 116).
\/ Escaped character. Matches a "/" character (char code 47).
| Alternation. Acts like a boolean OR. Matches the expression before or after the |.
l Character. Matches a "l" character (char code 108).
o Character. Matches a "o" character (char code 111).
c Character. Matches a "c" character (char code 99).
a Character. Matches a "a" character (char code 97).
l Character. Matches a "l" character (char code 108).
h Character. Matches a "h" character (char code 104).
o Character. Matches a "o" character (char code 111).
s Character. Matches a "s" character (char code 115).
t Character. Matches a "t" character (char code 116).
: Character. Matches a ":" character (char code 58).
4 Character. Matches a "4" character (char code 52).
0 Character. Matches a "0" character (char code 48).
8 Character. Matches a "8" character (char code 56).
0 Character. Matches a "0" character (char code 48).
\/ Escaped character. Matches a "/" character (char code 47).
)
( Capturing group #1. Groups multiple tokens together and creates a capture group for extracting a substring or using a backreference.
. Dot. Matches any character except line breaks.
* Star. Match 0 or more of the preceding token.
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much.I marked your answer as correct.Can you explain your solution and I edited my question a bit.Can you please, tell me if that can be done as well.

Comment: Sorry, I do not know how to explain it, But add the details of how the syntax treaty is done. PD: you're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `://localhost/`
with `://localhost:4080/`

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

text = [
    "https://localhost/subservice1",
    "https://localhost:4080/subservice1",
    "https://localhost/subservice1", 
    "https://localhost/subservice2"
]

regex = r'localhost/'
for x in text:
    result = re.sub(regex, "localhost:4080/", x)
    print(result)
```